# How to allow free-hand tagging at chosen jQuery

Tags: jquery, tags, jquery-chosen

I've used [chosen jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for tagging with suggestion box. I want to creating new tag by user which isn't exist at suggestion box. For example, if user want to make a new tag like "Red", it should be created. But, that plugin don't allow to do that. I'm trying to follow [their update](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events) on that issue but, I can't able to do it. How can I allow creating new tags for user?

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/v7j6ggk1/)

Not working scripts:

```
$(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [allow new values with chosen.js multiple select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385246/allow-new-values-with-chosen-js-multiple-select)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [basic example of how to do this](http://jsfiddle.net/0hxbcead/1/).

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="newTag"></input>
<button id="submitNewTag">Add new option</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#submitNewTag").on("click", function() {
    var newTag = $("#newTag").val();
    addNewOption(newTag);
});

function addNewOption(option) {
    $(".chosen-select").append("<option>" + option + "</option>");
    $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
}
```

Your problem seems to be that you don't know how to add a new option to the select list before triggering the update.  This can be done by appending a new `<option>` to the `<select>` list with jQuery's .append() function.

In my example, when a user clicks the "Add new option" button, the contents of the input box will be added to the select list, and then the chosen select list will be updated.